# AoT Build takes forever

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, aot, angular-aot

I've a angular 4.1.2 project with webpack and I'm trying to setup AoT build.

When I try to publish, the first build go fine, but the AoT build never ends.

Its already been building for several minutes and doesn't finish.

I'm trying to use AoT because the first load of the application is taking about 30/40 seconds sometimes.

[image: AoT Build]

Any idea of what is going on ?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Here my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: !isDevBuild ? ['@ngtools/webpack'] : ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: [{
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }]
                },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'to-string-loader',
                        isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize',
                        'resolve-url-loader'
                    ]
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                {
                    test: /\.(otf|eot|ttf|woff2?)(\?\S*)?$/,
                    use: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[path][name]-[hash].[ext]'
                },
                { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
                { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
                { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
                { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
                { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' }

            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin(),
                new CompressionPlugin({
                    asset: "[path].gz[query]",
                    algorithm: "gzip",
                    test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
                    threshold: 10240,
                    minRatio: 0
                }),
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    'process.env': {
                        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
                    }
                }),]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        devtool: isDevBuild ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: 'ClientApp/app/app.module.client#AppModule'
                }),
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```